# Similar conditions on a filtered table have different implications for delegations on Power Apps

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-canvas

New to Power Apps and delegations are driving me crazy.

On a canvas app, I have the following code which works fine:

```
ClearCollect(
    colFilteredByWHandProd,
    Filter(
        tracker_data,
        inv_dt <= CountDate.SelectedDate && wh_code = varSelWH && item_no = varSelProd
        )
);
```

However, if I try to add a fourth filter, which evaluates on a column on the list that is either "0" or "1", I get possible delegation error warnings:

```
ClearCollect(
    colFilteredByWHandProd,
    Filter(
        tracker_data,
        proj_val <> "1" && inv_dt <= CountDate.SelectedDate && wh_code = varSelWH && item_no = varSelProd
        )
);
```

This doesn't make any sense. Both the `wh_code = varSelWH` and the `item_no = varSelProd` portions donot throw any error warnings. Furthermore, the item_no, wh_code and proj_val fields on the SP list are single line text fields.

I have tried changing the order and even reducing the number of filters. But consistently, I only get the error warning on `proj_val <> "1"`

One possible culprit is that the proj_val field on the SP list is a calculated column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of chaining filter conditions, you should [nest multiple Filter() functions](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Power-Apps/Does-delegation-extend-to-nested-filters/m-p/783506/highlight/true#M249601) to overcome delegation.

A 'not' operation is not delegable to SharePoint, so implement a logic where it is not the innermost filter.